# How to provide culture to use when mapping properties in AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

At first some base classes:

```
public class Source
{
    public DateTimeOffset InstallationDate { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public string InstallationDate { get; set; }
}

public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
    }
}

var source = new Source { InstallationDate = DateTime.UtcNow };
```

And here is the running method:

```
    public async Task<Destination> CreateDestinationFrom(source)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        // This method does some magic stuff to retrieve the current customers culture
        var cultureInfo = await GetCustomerCulture();
        // How to provide this culture, to AutoMapper?
        var dest = mapper.Map<Destination>(source);

        return dest;
    }
```

The above method is called within our backend and can be performed for multiple customers in parallel. Due to this fact, we can't use `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo`, cause a task is not a thread. Also, because AutoMapper at the end calls the default type converter (which is in this case equivalent to `.ToString()`) I'm quite sure to make my culture-specific conversion, it must be announced within the profile by using `.ForMember()`. But how can I provide the desired culture to my own value converter within AutoMapper when calling the `.Map()` function?

One idea by myself was to make my own class, that composes from `Source` and `CultureInfo` and then convert from `SourceAndCulture` to `Destination`, but this seems very clumsy to me.

I've already seen that the `.Map()` method has an overload that takes an `Action<IMappingOperationOptions<TSource, TDestination>>` as an additional argument and maybe this can help to solve this issue, but I couldn't see how to incorporate it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you on an ancient version of .Net? Because according to this link, the missing support for flowing culture into async tasks was added in .Net 4.6. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Globalization_CultureInfo_CurrentCulture

Comment: I'm on .Net Core 5. But the problem is, that I could have multiple parallel tasks, where each on has a different culture and setting the culture on the thread level would lead to racing condititions between the running tasks (if two tasks with different culture would be executed on the same thread).

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu: Yes, that should work. Simply didn't see that in the documenation. Thanks. I'm going to test it and will maybe self-answering it if no one is faster. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Lucian Bargaoanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811700/lucian-bargaoanu) providing the link to the needed section within the AutoMapper documentation, I could solving the problem by myself.

Here is the mapping profile:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.InstallationDate, conf => conf.MapFrom((src, _, _, context) => src.InstallationDate.ToString((CultureInfo)context.Items["culture"])));
    }
}
```

And here how to call the `.Map()` method:

```
var dest = mapper.Map<Destination>(source, opt => { opt.Items["culture"] = cultureInfo; });
```